# Perl: Writing compactly three loops between 0 and X, 0 and Y and 0 and Z

Tags: perl

Assume I have a "make_members" method like this.

```
sub make_members {  
    my ($number_members) = @_;
    my $rows = SomeDBIModule->select(); 
    my $count = @$rows;             
    for ( my $i = $count + 1; $i < $count + 1 + $number_members; $i++ ) {
          $rows->insert(
              name => "name".$i, 
              type => "A",
              created_at => time,                 
         );                    
   }                                                        
 }
```

So far so good. Now imagine the method can take as input, the number of users type a, type b and type c that its desired:

```
sub make_members {  
    my ($number_members, $n_members_type_a, $n_members_type_b, $n_members_type_c) = @_;
    #....
```

To write this what first comes to my mind is to make 3 loops. The first one

```
     for ( my $i = $count + 1; $i < $count + 1 + $n_members_type_a; $i++ ){
          $rows->insert(
              name => "name".$i, 
              type => "A",
      #....
```

The second one between  $count + 1 and $n_members_type_b.
The third one between  $count + 1 and $n_members_type_c.

That just looks too long and awful.
Is there a better way of writing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Three or more, use a `for`”.

Just pack it inside another loop

```
sub make_members {
  my %number_members_for_type;
  @number_members_for_type{qw/A B C/} = @_;
  my $rows = ...;
  while (my ($type, $num) = each %number_members_for_type) {
    for my $i ( @$rows + 1 .. @$rows + $num ) {
      $rows->insert(
        name => "name$i",
        type => $type,
        ...
      )
    }
  }
}
```

This assumes it is called like `make_members($n_type_a, $n_type_b, $n_type_c)`.

Using a hash for the arguments lets this scale nicely.

We can generalize this if a hash is passed as argument. If the `name` property has to be an unique ID, *and* insertions are only done by this function, then we can manage that elegantly as well:

```
sub make_inserter {
  my ($rows) = @_;
  my $id_counter = @$rows;
  return sub {
    my %type2nums = @_;
    while (my ($type, $num) = each %type2nums) {
      for my $i ($id_counter + 1 .. $id_counter + $num) {
        $rows->insert(
          name => "name$i",
          type => $type,
          ...
        );
      }
      $id_counter += $num;
    }
  };
}

...

# Careful! Do not make an inserter for the same handle twice!
my $make_members = make_inserter(SomeDBIModule->select);
$make_members->(A => 2, B => 3);
```

If the order of the keys is important, we should rather do this, because the order of hash keys is undefined:

```
  ... # as before
  return sub {
    while (my ($type, $num) = splice @_, 0, 2) {
      ... # as before
    }
  };
```

Comment: thanks. So the input of make_members  is a hash right? E.g. make_members (+{ A => 1, B => 3, C => 5 });

Comment: i also couldnt help but noticing that with this answer, if there are 2 ypes A and 3 types B, the names for types A would be name1, name2 and the names for type B would be name1, name2, name3... If say name is a primary key, that would give an error. $name$i is valid if $i never goes back, but here $i goes back once a loop is over and another one starts

Comment: @adriancdperu I updated with another solution that you may like more. This allows you to pass in a flat key-value list, and solves the problem of recurring names. It uses an *anonymous function*, which is a so-called *closure* over the `$id_counter` variable

Answer (score 0):

Repeating many similar params to a method is often a sign that there is some simplification possible.

So instead of taking a list of numbers, accept the type as a parameter:

```
sub make_members {  
    my ($number_members, $member_type) = @_;
```

and later:

```
$rows->insert(
              name => "name".$i, 
              type => $member_type,
              created_at => time,                 
         );
```

Then factor calling code appropriately. For instance to create x times "A", y times "B", z times "C":

```
%numbers_of = ( "A" => 4, "B" => 5, "C" => 2 );
for my $type (keys %numbers_of) {
    make_members( $numbers_of{ $type }, $type );
}
```

Comment: Ah, this doesn't work because of embedded scoped counter in the `make_members` method, which means you can only call the routine once. I'd probably factor that out too, a routine you can only call once safely is going to cause you a headache at some point. However, it becomes a more delicate decision, based on what the rest of the code does.